Adding a Admin Style Table in a Wordpress 4.x Page
I'm trying to add an admin style table in a regular page with a sample below. The code is inside the theme's functions.php.
It seems the class is not loaded and crashes so the echo after is not called.
I have no problems creating tables as a plugin and inside an admin section, but trying to do it in a regular page.
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

if ( ! class_exists( 'WP_List_Table' ) ) {
    require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php';
}

class Transactions_List_Table extends WP_List_Table {
    
}

function render_transactions_list_page() {
    $transactions_table = new Transactions_List_Table();    
    echo 'Hello';
}

// Add this to a shortcode if you want to display it on a regular page
add_shortcode( 'transactions_table', 'render_transactions_list_page' );



Why 4.x? that's out of date and insecure.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

We need to made few changes in the code so that it works properly. Here is the updated code.
<?php
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

if ( ! class_exists( 'WP_List_Table' ) ) {
    require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php';
}

class Transactions_List_Table extends WP_List_Table {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct( array(
            'singular' => 'transaction',
            'plural'   => 'transactions',
            'ajax'     => false,
        ) );
    }

    // Here are preparing our items.
    public function prepare_items() {
        // Here we would normally retrieve data from the database.
        $this->items = array(
            array( 'id' => 1, 'name' => 'Transaction 1', 'amount' => '$100' ),
            array( 'id' => 2, 'name' => 'Transaction 2', 'amount' => '$200' ),
        );

        $this->_column_headers = array( $this->get_columns(), array(), array() );
    }

    public function get_columns() {
        return array(
            'id'     => __( 'ID', 'textdomain' ),
            'name'   => __( 'Transaction Name', 'textdomain' ),
            'amount' => __( 'Amount', 'textdomain' ),
        );
    }

    public function column_default( $item, $column_name ) {
        switch ( $column_name ) {
            case 'id':
            case 'name':
            case 'amount':
                return $item[ $column_name ];
            default:
                return '';
        }
    }

    public function display() {
        echo '<div class="wrap">';
        echo '<h2>' . __( 'Transactions', 'textdomain' ) . '</h2>';
        parent::display();
        echo '</div>';
    }
}

function render_transactions_list_page() {
    $transactions_table = new Transactions_List_Table();
    $transactions_table->prepare_items();
    ob_start();
    $transactions_table->display();
    return ob_get_clean();
}

// We have added this to a shortcode to display it on a regular page.
add_shortcode( 'transactions_table', 'render_transactions_list_page' );

